# Toggle visibility of table row

Tags: jquery, arrays, html-table

I'm having to code a filter for a table with many options.

My approach atm is:

On the for loop that fetches the rows, push the option's information to an array:

```
<script>
      if (arrayTypes == null){
        var arrayTypes = [];
        arrayTypes.push("{{option}}");
      }
      else{
        arrayTypes.push("{{option}}");     
      }
</script>
```

when the loop is finished I have an array matching the type and index position of each option with the table, so:

**Table row,option    |    Array index**

Row 1,A........| [0] = A

Row 2,B........| [1] = B

Row 3,A........| [2] = A

Row 4,A........| [3] = A

etc...

Now I'm trying to set it up like this:

```
$("#type_filters").on('click',"button[name='hide-A']",function(){
    for(var i=0;i<=arrayTypes.length;i++){
      if(arrayTypes[i] == 'A'){
        $("#my-table tr.option")[i].toggle();
      }
    }
  })
```

but I'm getting an error in the log that `toggle()` is **not** a function.

Could someone help?

Comment: Try using `$($("#my-table tr.option")[i]).toggle();`

Comment: @Idanb this worked, don't you want to post an answer?

Comment: Its ok you can accept Tyr's answer as well, but thank you for the thoughtfulness :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#my-table tr.option")[i]` isn't a jQuery object, so toggle isn't available. You get the specific HTML Element. To use toggle you have to put it back into jQuery:

```
var row = $("#my-table tr.option")[i];
$(row).toggle();
```

Comment: This worked along with Idanb's answer in comment section. You'd like to improve your answer?

Comment: My answer was 1 minute earlier. :o

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#type_filters").on('click',"button[name='hide-A']",function(){
  $.each(arrayTypes,function(i,v) {
      if(v == 'A'){
       var _thisRow = $("#my-table tr.option")[i];
       $(_thisRow).toggle();
      }
  });
});
```